# How do I send multiple check box values in database using php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create a check box for attendance of student ...
Suppose
There is a text box asking for no. of students 
in a class if we enter 10 then 10 check boxes will come using for loop... for taking attendance each row having two check boxes one for present and the other for absent
So how would we send the values of the cheboxes to the database when attendance is submitted...

Comment: I think you just need one checkbox for each student and mark if the user is absent or not.

Comment: Can you show us the code you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can send multiple value for various inputs using the, what's known in php, as short array tags(not the same as HTML, just coincidentally the same syntax).

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="value 1">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="value 2">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="value 3">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="value 4">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="value 5">
```

Notice the `[]` after the `name="checkbox..`.

You can retrieve them using `$_GET` or `$_POST` or whatever the framework you're using abstracts it to.

They will show up as an array with the key being the name of the checkboxes(in our case `checkbox`) and with the values as the value of the checkbox itself.

Answer (score 0):

Set the name in the form to `checks[]` for all the checkboxes input you have.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checks[]">
<input type="checkbox" name="checks[]">
...
<input type="checkbox" name="checks[]">
```

Then in your php code and you can access them as an array:

```
$checks = array($_POST['checks'][]);
```